# Use regex for split in Java

Tags: java, android, regex, formatting

I have String **IR800610000000700805312546** in Java, I need convert to

**IR80-0610-0000-0070-0805-3125-46**.

I use split for the string, but not work

```
String[] arrayList = number.split("(\\w{4})");
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
        result.append(arrayList[i]);
        if (i != arrayList.length - 1) {
            result.append(separator);
        }
}
```

Can I use String formatter?

Answer (score 2):

You could use replaceall instead of split and use your capturing group followed by a negative lookahead to assert not the  end of the string `(\w{4})(?!\$)`.

In the replacement use the capturing group followed by a hyphen `$1-`

```
String number = "IR800610000000700805312546";
number = number.replaceAll("(\w{4})(?!$)", "$1-");
System.out.println(number); // IR80-0610-0000-0070-0805-3125-46
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/Kuhb9T) | [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T7EQzo/1)

Comment: My bad. If the last match is 4 characters there will be a trailing dash.

Use a negative lookahead `.{4}(?!$)`

Comment: @JFord You are right, thank you! I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easiest just to use a `StringBuilder` directly, without explicit splitting:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String delim = "";
for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i += 4) {
  result.append(delim);
  delim = "-";

  result.append(number, i, min(i + 4, number.length()));
}
```

This approach will likely be at least an order of magnitude faster than using regular expressions, because it does far less work.

Comment: @RasoulMiri you are already using `StringBuilder` and a loop. There is simply no need to bring regex into this.